# Copying a URL into latex

Tags: formatting

I have a URL(below) that I want to put into latex as a reference but as it has % symbols in then it gets commented out. Is there a way to do this so it displays normally? Thanks

http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/nph-objsearch?objname=SDSS%20J114833.14%2b193003.2&extend=no&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA+or+Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES

Comment: The 'url` packages `\url` command has no problems with embedded `%`, no need to comment them

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `hyperref` package, which automatically handles the `%` sign correctly and also makes the link clickable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    Also see \url{http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/nph-objsearch?objname=SDSS%20J114833.14%2b193003.2&extend=no&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA+or+Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES} for more information
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The borders only appear in PDF viewers to indicate that the link is clickable, but don't get printed.

**Edit**: in many cases, one can also reduce the length of the URL by removing some parameters. For example, the link http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/nph-objsearch?objname=SDSS+J114833.14%2b193003.2&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES yields virtually the same page as your version. Should some poor soul indeed have to type the full URL, they'll thank you.

Comment: In many cases, including more of the url than required can give away things you might not want to give away -- for example your username for a service.